# async await in javascript array map

Tags: javascript, debugging, async-await, es6-promise, array-map

```js
function returnPromise(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(item * item)
        }, 1000)
    })
}

async function main() {
    const items = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    const resultArr = []
    items.map(async (item) => {
        const result = await returnPromise(item)
        console.log(result)
        resultArr.push(result)
    })}
    console.log(resultArr)
```

i tested array map can work with async / await. 
and i expect async/await works so that variable `result` results to square of item 
and `resultArr` results to array of square of `items`.

But, stdout displays that 
first, resultArr prints out empty array 
and `console.log` in `map` prints out sequentially.

When i debug the code, control flow stops at `await returnPromise(item)`, doesn't go down to `console.log(result)` and directly go to `console.log(resultArr)` 
and after stack unwind and the Promise resolved, `console.log(result)` executed.

How can it happen?? it works like `console.log(result)` is callback, but they are in same code block.
I think `console.log(result)` should work when `await returnPromise` executed. 
And I know i should have used Promise.all and didn't have to use async /await like above code but i just want to know why this situation happens...

Comment: `const resultArr = await Promise.all(items.map(returnPromise))`